# Running microphone signal through stereo jack

Tags: audio, microphone

I've recently mounted a 3.5mm connector onto a walkie talkie, so that I can plug in a headset. It works really well, though I've had the idea that since it's a stereo jack and the singal is mono, I could use the second connector pin to run signal from microphone to the walkie talkie. I'm not sure how though. Would connecting the microphone's output to one of the microphone contacts on the walkie talkie be enough? If so should it be + or - ? How do electronics usually handle electret microphones? 
Do send a constant current to one pin and use the second as output (treat the mic as a switch) or is it different?
Thanks for any suggestions.

PS: just to clear any confusion I've already attached the microphone output to the stereo jack, I just need to figure out how to attach it to the walkie talkie

Answer (score 1):

Find the existing wiring to the walkie-talkie internal microphone and wire it through your added 3.5mm connector. Most of those 3.5mm connectors have "closed circuit" switches which will connect the radio's internal microphone to the radio circuit except when you plug in your headset.

Comment: So what should I do is to connect the microphone on the headset to the common ground terminal (if it isn't already) and it's output to the radio's microphone positive terminal?

Comment: First you must establish that your walkie-talkie radio uses an electret capsule microphone. Some of them use the speaker as a microphone while transmitting.  Which kind is yours?

Comment: Yes, there's an electret microphone.

Answer (score 1):

Padding...  This should work for you:

[image]